# Calculate average of digits in python string

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to create a function which would count all the odd digits in a string and would return the average number calculated as a float. For example, if the string is ("*1*2*3*4"), the function should return the average of 1 and 3 (odd digits in string) which is 2. If there are no odd numbers, the function should return 0. I know the code below is incorrect but that's as far as I've been able to get. Thank you for your help.

```
def Odd(ww):
Result = 0.0
for i in (ww):
    if i.isdigit():
        if int(i) % 2 != 0:
            Result = Result + int(i)
            if int(i) % 2 == 0:
                return Result 
return Result // 2
```

Comment: Can you say anything about what is incorrect about it?  Besides the indenting?

Comment: the result // 2, struggling to figure out how to get the average of the odd digits in a string.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need a count to find the number of odd numbers found in the string:

```
def Odd(ww):
  Result = 0.0
  count = 0
  for i in (ww):
     if i.isdigit():
        if int(i) % 2 != 0:
           Result = Result + int(i)
           count += 1
  return Result if not Result else Result/float(count)

print(Odd("*1*2*3*4"))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: The function works for odd numbers however, if enter a string with no odd numbers such as 2*4*6*8, the function should simply return 0.0 but in this case It returns an error code.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't simply divide by 2; you have to count the quantity of odd digits and divide by that count.
- You can't quit at the first even digits; you have to finish the string to find all the odds.

The problems are at the end of your code:

```
            if int(i) % 2 == 0:
                return Result   # Nope -- keep a count and a running sum to use later.
return Result // 2   # Nope -- divide the sum by the count.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
def avg(l):
    if (l is None or len(l) == 0):
        return 0
    return sum(l) / len(l)

def odd(l):
    return [e for e in l if e % 2 != 0]

def oddavg(l):
    return float(avg(odd(l)))

def onlydigit(s):
    return (int(c) for c in s if c.isdigit())

def oddavgstr(s):
    return oddavg(onlydigit(s))


assert avg([1,2,3]) == 2
assert avg(None) == 0
assert odd([1,2,3]) == [1,3]
assert oddavg([1,2,3,4]) == 2
assert oddavg([2,4,6]) == 0
assert list(onlydigit('h3l00')) == [3, 0, 0]
assert oddavgstr('1*2*3*4') == 2
assert oddavgstr('2*2') == 0
```

I'm using function composition to achieve your goal. The `avg` can be found at numpy but the above is just enough. We covert the string to a list of digits (ints), the isolate the odds and calculate the average.

I hope this helps. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def odd(val):
    result = 0
    count = 0
    for i in val:
        if i.isdigit() and int(i) % 2 != 0:
            result += int(i)
            count += 1
    return float(result / count) if result > 0 else 0.0
```

*Note: Average is calculated with (sum of values) / (number of values)*

*For example: (1 + 3 + 5) / (3) = 3*

Comment: The function works for odd numbers however, if enter a string with no odd numbers such as 2*4*6*8, the function should simply return 0.0 but in this case I get an error.

Comment: @Erik thanks for pointing that out. It should work now (updated return statement)

Comment: Thank you so much!